# C# .NET framework 4.5.2 and Swashbuckle

Tags: c#, .net, swagger, openapi, swashbuckle

I have a .NET framework 4.5.2 API and I want to generate a swagger documentation for an API area, specifically, for all the endpoints that match /api/...

I have installed the [Swashbuckle.NET45](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.Net45) package, and this is what my current `SwaggerConfig.cs` looks like:

```
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.EnableSwagger(c =>
            {
                c.SingleApiVersion("v1", "API");
                c.DocumentFilter<ExcludeControllersFilter>();
                c.ResolveConflictingActions(apiDescriptions => apiDescriptions.First());
            })
        .EnableSwaggerUi(c =>
            {
            });
    }
}

public class ExcludeControllersFilter : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer)
    {
        var pathsToRemove = swaggerDoc.paths
            .Where(pathItem => !pathItem.Key.Contains("API/"))
            .ToList();

        foreach (var item in pathsToRemove)
        {
            swaggerDoc.paths.Remove(item.Key);
        }
    }
}
```

and I have it registered using

```
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        ...
        SwaggerConfig.Register(config);
        ...
    }
```

Is there something I forgot to do?

by navigating to `http://localhost/HiddenAPIName/swagger/ui/index` it says `fetching resource list: http://localhost/HiddenAPIName/swagger/docs/v1; Please wait`, then I get a StackOverflowException in `SendAsync`, and by navigating to `http://localhost/HiddenAPIName/swagger/ui/swagger.json` I get

```
{
  "Message": "An error has occurred.",
  "ExceptionMessage": "Mapping not found - swagger.json",
  "ExceptionType": "Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi.AssetNotFound",
  "StackTrace": "   at Swashbuckle.SwaggerUi.EmbeddedAssetProvider.GetAsset(String rootUrl, String path)\r\n   at Swashbuckle.Application.SwaggerUiHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)"
}
```

Comment: 4.5.2 went out of support a while ago. The oldest supported .NET Framework version is 4.6.2 but there's no real reason to use anything less than 4.8 or even better, .NET Core. In fact, Swashbuckle for .NET Framework hasn't posted a new version since 2017. The current versions are only for ASP.NET Core

Comment: Why are you targeting .NET Framework if you care about Swagger? The Swagger libraries themselves didn't exist in the 4.5.2 timeframe. The [Swashbuckle.WebApi](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.WebApi) hasn't been updated in 6 years and has no maintainers. Issues aren't being answered

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos the existing infrastructure has existed for a long time before my time, I am not going to update the entire infrastructure for a Swagger documentation. I have found a package Swashbuckle.Net45 which seems to work

Comment: Why post a question if it works? Except it doesn't. That package was an [even older fork](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Swashbuckle.Net45) (2015) whose Github project no longer exists. The final proper Swashbuckle package was published in 2017. 6 years later I doubt anyone remembers how it worked.

Comment: `I am not going to update the entire infrastructure for a Swagger documentation` how about TLS 1.2/1.3? Because 4.5.2 didn't support TLS 1.2 automatically, which was a big problem for applications 6 years ago, as all major services switched to TLS 1.2. 4.6.2 was the first version that automatically supports the best available TLS version